# Interaction between two factors as Random effects in mixed model in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, biostatistics, brms

I would like to know how to write random effects of two interacting factors. For example, I have 6 species which were planted in 48 plots and replicated in two blocks. There are in total 48 combinations (all possible 1, 2, 3, 5, and 6 species combinations ) for the 6 species.

By design, combinations are actually nested within diversity: the combinations are the correct replicates for each diversity level; hence the effect of diversity should be tested against the (random) variation among combinations within diversity levels.Since, diversity or species richness is a continuous variable I can't consider combinations are nested within diversity.

I would like to make the interaction between block and combination as random effect. I am not sure how to write in properly in mixed models in R.